# Can corresponding authors include their personal website to be contacted?

Tags: publications, website, correspondence

I wonder if corresponding authors in peer-reviewed publications can include their personal websites to be contacted besides their address, telephone and email.

In the case that the corresponding author is between two jobs, she/he can still be contacted in case her/his previous email account is deleted once her/his previous job has come to and end.

Comment: Note that the corresponding author is usually the most senior member, less likely to move. He should be able to track down his former advisees.

Comment: @Davidmh: for that matter, many (most?) journals include some form of contact information for all the authors, even [when the list can be 12 pages long](http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.7214). The main problem of course is when none of the listed authors can be contacted at their listed addresses.

Comment: @Davidmh: In CS subfields that I am familiar with, the corresponding author is usually the most *junior* member. No professor I know would want to be bothered with "low-level" editorial requests. (Contact addresses, at least e-mail, of all authors are generally included on the papers, though.)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper in my experience (Physics and Bioinformatics), the published articled has only one author marked as "to whom correspondence should be addressed". This is completely different than the editorial process, where you are the least concerned about persistence of the email (you are unlikely to leave, and if you do, you just tell the editor while still in review).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of including a personal website, why not just include a permanent e-mail address?

- Simplest would be just get a Gmail account (or any free webmail provider) for your work correspondence.
- If you want a more professional looking account, sometimes professional organizations can provide to dues-paying members e-mail forwarding services. For example, the American Mathematical Society [offers precisely one such service](http://www.ams.org/membership/individual/benefits/mail_forward).
- Also, if you have a personal website, maybe you can set up a mailbox under its domain that you use to receive work correspondence?

One other thing you can do is to sign-up for a [digital researcher identification](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/28240/94) so that your publications are properly linked to each other. That way readers may be able to track down your more recent publications and find your contact info there.

---

But to the question you actually asked: I am sure it depends greatly on journal and publisher, so you are much better off asking them than us.