# Can I use an accented Chinese name when publishing a paper in academia?

Tags: publications, personal-name

My name is in Chinese. When it is transliterated into the Latin alphabet, a lot of other names come out the same. Despite some journals accepting Chinese character names, most journals don't. In this case, instead of a plain Latin alphabet transliteration, I'm considering adding a diacritic (the tone of the character in Chinese). Is this acceptable? Would it cause any issues? I know about ORCID, but a unique name is still valuable.

e.g., instead of Hong I want to use Hóng.

Comment: Did you mean "Hóng"?

Comment: @scaaahu Correct.

Comment: I think this is a great idea. As an ignorant American, however, I will note that this may not achieve the goal you wish, as I have no idea how to pronounce Hóng differently from Hong.

Comment: @jakebeal It doesn't matter: the visual difference is more important.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I always list myself in all my papers as José F. Martínez. Some people are better than others at replicating the accents in citations. Search engines have become much better at matching papers to names with accents even if citations won't include them, so in terms of missing citations (e.g., Google Scholar) I don't think it should be an issue.

My students definitely know how to write the accents :)

Comment: The issue I'm concerned is that this name is not my legal name (no accent on passport).

Comment: People use author names that are slight variations of legal names all the time: Joe, Doug, etc. Maybe you can put a guide to pronunciation on your web page and list yourself with your "normal" (unaccented it seems) name?

Comment: @xuhdev A related question [Pen name similar with real name: Zu Yangzu instead of Zu Yang for papers](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/56073/546)

Comment: If you use a variation of the legal name, what name do you fill in the copyright form? The legal name or the variation?

Comment: @xuhdev Your comment sounds another good question: If my name on the published paper is different from my legal name, what name do I fill in the copyright form?